# PHP time ahead of MySQL time

Tags: php, sql, mysql, timezone

I run PHP and MySQL on the same machine, but both report different times.

I set the timezones by the following methods:

PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
```

MySQL:

```
SET time_zone = "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur";
```

The difference between two times is always exactly 24 seconds.
Any idea why this is happening?
I thought the times must be same because both reside on the same machine!

Comment: Are you sure that 24 seconds isn't passing between when you get the value from one & compare with the other?

Comment: No, I am comparing both the times in the same scripting run. The maximum difference should be 1 second (if the second changes between first line and second line of code).

Comment: Are you running PHP and MySQL on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this question:
[Why does MySQL CONVERT_TZ alter the seconds after timezone adjustment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987616/why-does-mysql-converttz-alter-the-seconds-after-timezone-adjustment)